# How to create a read-only class property in Python?

Tags: python, class, properties

Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
class foo:
    x = 4
    @property
    @classmethod
    def number(cls):
        return x
```

Then I would like the following to work:

```
>>> foo.number
4
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. Instead of given me `4` it gives me `<property object at 0x101786c58>`. Is there any way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `property` descriptor always returns itself when accessed from a class (ie. when `instance` is `None` in its `__get__` method).

If that's not what you want, you can write a new descriptor that always uses the class object (`owner`) instead of the instance:

```
>>> class classproperty(object):
...     def __init__(self, getter):
...         self.getter= getter
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
...         return self.getter(owner)
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     x= 4
...     @classproperty
...     def number(cls):
...         return cls.x
... 
>>> Foo().number
4
>>> Foo.number
4
```

Comment: This isn't a read-only attribute. Python descriptors intentionally do not intercept class-level calls to `setattr` and `delattr` with their `__set__` and `__delete__` methods. So `Foo.number = 6` could still work.

Answer (score 76):

This will make `Foo.number` a *read-only* property:

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    @property
    def number(cls):
        return cls.x

class Foo(object, metaclass=MetaFoo):
    x = 4

print(Foo.number)
# 4

Foo.number = 6
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

---

**Explanation**: The usual scenario when using `@property` looks like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def number(self):
        ...
foo = Foo()
```

A property defined in `Foo` is read-only with respect to its instances. That is, `foo.number = 6` would raise an `AttributeError`.

Analogously, if you want `Foo.number` to raise an `AttributeError` you would need to setup a property defined in `type(Foo)`. Hence the need for a metaclass.

---

Note that this read-onlyness is not immune from hackers.
The property can be made writable by changing Foo's
class:

```
class Base(type): pass
Foo.__class__ = Base

# makes Foo.number a normal class attribute
Foo.number = 6   
print(Foo.number)
```

prints

```
6
```

or, if you wish to make `Foo.number` a settable property,

```
class WritableMetaFoo(type): 
    @property
    def number(cls):
        return cls.x
    @number.setter
    def number(cls, value):
        cls.x = value
Foo.__class__ = WritableMetaFoo

# Now the assignment modifies `Foo.x`
Foo.number = 6   
print(Foo.number)
```

also prints

```
6
```

Comment: @unutbu : Is it possible to perform the reverse : that is make Foo.number writable without rebuilding the Foo class.

Comment: @user2284570: You can make `Foo.number` writable by changing `Foo`'s metaclass from `MetaFoo` to something else. You could either make `number` a setable property or simply not mention it, in which case setting `Foo.number` would make `Foo.number` a normal class attribute. I've added some code above to show what I mean.

Comment: @unutbu : And would I be able to change it’s metaclass back ? Would this work for code objects ?

Answer (score 17):

I agree with [unubtu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203434/608191); it seems to work, however, it doesn't work with this precise syntax on **Python 3** (specifically, Python 3.4 is what I struggled with). Here's how one must form the pattern under Python 3.4 to make things work, it seems:

```py
class MetaFoo(type):
   @property
   def number(cls):
      return cls.x

class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
   x = 4

print(Foo.number)
# 4

Foo.number = 6
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 8):

Problem with solutions above is that it wouldn't work for accessing class variables from instance variable:

```
print(Foo.number)
# 4

f = Foo()
print(f.number)
# 'Foo' object has no attribute 'number'
```

Moreover, using metaclass explicit is not so nice, as using regular `property` decorator.

I tried to solve this problems. Here how it works now:

```
@classproperty_support
class Bar(object):
    _bar = 1

    @classproperty
    def bar(cls):
        return cls._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(cls, value):
        cls._bar = value


# @classproperty should act like regular class variable.
# Asserts can be tested with it.
# class Bar:
#     bar = 1


assert Bar.bar == 1

Bar.bar = 2
assert Bar.bar == 2

foo = Bar()
baz = Bar()
assert foo.bar == 2
assert baz.bar == 2

Bar.bar = 50
assert baz.bar == 50
assert foo.bar == 50
```

As you see, we have `@classproperty` that works same way as `@property` for class variables. Only thing we will need is additional `@classproperty_support` class decorator.

Solution also works for read-only class properties.

Here's implementation:

```
class classproperty:
    """
    Same as property(), but passes obj.__class__ instead of obj to fget/fset/fdel.
    Original code for property emulation:
    https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/descriptor.html#properties
    """
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj.__class__)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj.__class__, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj.__class__)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)


def classproperty_support(cls):
    """
    Class decorator to add metaclass to our class.
    Metaclass uses to add descriptors to class attributes, see:
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/26634248/1113207
    """
    class Meta(type):
        pass

    for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
        if isinstance(obj, classproperty):
            setattr(Meta, name, property(obj.fget, obj.fset, obj.fdel))

    class Wrapper(cls, metaclass=Meta):
        pass
    return Wrapper
```

**Note:** code isn't tested much, feel free to note if it doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 8):

The solution of Mikhail Gerasimov is quite complete. Unfortunately, it was one drawback. If you have a class using his classproperty, no child class can use it due to an 
`TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases` with `class Wrapper`.

Fortunately, this can be fixed. Just inherit from the metaclass of the given class when creating `class Meta`.

```
def classproperty_support(cls):
  """
  Class decorator to add metaclass to our class.
  Metaclass uses to add descriptors to class attributes, see:
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26634248/1113207
  """
  # Use type(cls) to use metaclass of given class
  class Meta(type(cls)): 
      pass

  for name, obj in vars(cls).items():
      if isinstance(obj, classproperty):
          setattr(Meta, name, property(obj.fget, obj.fset, obj.fdel))

  class Wrapper(cls, metaclass=Meta):
      pass
  return Wrapper
```