# MyClass.attr VS type(self).attr VS separate @classmethod

Tags: python, class, attributes

Say I have a (normal bound) method in my class that has to access class variables (like a counter in `__init__`). If I want to modify class varaibles, I see three possibilities:

1. Use `type(self)` or `self.__class__` (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class), I chose `type` over `__class__`, as I'm using Python 3 so "old-style" classes don't apply)
2. Use the name of the class. This works well unless the name is rebound.
3. write a `@classmethod` specifically for changing class variables. This is the most complicated, but also the most clear (IMO) approach.

The three methods would be written like this:

```
class MyClass:
    counter = 0

    def f1(self):
        type(self).counter += 1

    def f2(self):
        MyClass.counter += 1

    def f3(self):
        self._count()
    @classmethod
    def _count(cls):
        cls.counter += 1
```

**Is there a clear "best" option and which one is it or are they all more or less equivalent and it's just "what I like most"? Does inheritance change anything?**

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward use-case for a classmethod, imo. I don't really see it as appreciably more complicated than the alternatives. Using functions to split your code up into smaller, composable parts makes your code *less complicated* overall, the way I see it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, it makes a method do what one line of code does otherwise; it obviously separates well, but adds a layer of complexity. If I had more stuff to change, I'd certainly use a classmethod. ---- I'd be happy to see an answer based on your comment.

Comment: Are you inheriting from this class anywhere?

Comment: @DavisHerring in this specific case not, but I might in the future, so I'd love an answer which addresses both and explains why a different approach might be applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **derive** classes from the one defining your variable (and presumably the method assigning to it), using `type(self)` stores (the new value of) the attribute on the object’s **actual class**.  That can be quite useful, but in your example is [surely wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8576620/8586227).

Using a class method is just the same, except that the subclass could **override** the method: this might make the complex case work, but does nothing to fix the simple inheritance case.

Using the name of the class is the simple, **idiomatic** answer and avoids any confusion from subclasses.  In the absence of concern over rebinding that name, this should be the default even without any inheritance.  If that is a concern, you can **stash** the class object in a couple of different ways:

```
class A:
  counter=0

  # use the magic behind super():
  def _count1(): __class__.counter+=1

  # inject the class object:
  @staticmethod
  def _count2(cls): cls.counter+=1
A._count2.__defaults__=A,

# inject via a closure:
def capture(cls):
  def _count(): cls.counter+=1
  return _count
A._count3=staticmethod(capture(A))
```

The `__class__` trick can of course be used directly, without a wrapper method, but it’s a bit ugly; internally, it’s very similar to the last approach with `capture`.  One thing that doesn’t work is trying to make a function that refers to the class’s *dictionary*, since those are protected for optimization reasons.