# How to apply properties on classmethod?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, properties, setter

My question is simple: How can I add properties and setter to classmethod ?

Here is my code:

```
class Ingredient():
     __max_stock = 100
     __stock = 0
     __prix = 0

     def __init__(self):
         pass

     @classmethod
     @property
     def prix(cls):
         return cls.__prix
     @classmethod
     @prix.setter
     def prix(cls, value):
         assert isinstance(value, int) and int(abs(value)) == value
         cls.__prix = value


Ingredient.prix = 10        #should be OK
Ingredient.prix = 'text'    #should raise an error
Ingredient.prix = 10.5      #should raise an error too
```

Problem is that the setter doesn't work when the var is a class variable.
Here is the error I get :

```
AttributeError: 'classmethod' object has no attribute 'setter'
```

I use Python 3.x

Comment: does it have to be a `classmethod`? why not just have a default value passed to the constructor that you can change when needed?

Comment: I'm not sure `property` and `classmethod` are *intended* to work together

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for having beautified my code.
Second, the reason I want to keep classmethod is that the price is common to all ingredients. So when I want to change the price, all instances will have an updated price (and so on with stock and max_stock)

Comment: @EliasRhouzlane, I think my answers accomplishes that. Can you test it out?

Comment: I would just document that `Ingredient.prix` must be a non-negative integer. If the user sets it to something else, well, *caveat programmator*. You can't stop them from setting `Ingredient._Ingredient__prix` to something directly anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in python >= 3.9 per https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#id27
See `For example, a classmethod and property could be chained together`

You may have a use case where you only want to calculate a classmethod property one time then keep using that value. If that is the case and this calculation needs to be done on subclasses, one could use [**init_subclass**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) in python >= 3.6 to do this

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.prix = cls._prix

class B(A):
    _prix = 0
```

Comment: Note that, as of Python 3.11, this is deprecated again: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92379

Answer (score 1):

Don't use classmethod directly in this way.  If you need a classproperty decorator that is analogous to the instance property decorator including the possibility of setters, check out [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-can-i-make-a-class-property-in-python/5192374#5192374) for some good patterns.  (You could also do it with a metaclass, but there's probably no reason to get into that.)