# In python which method has to be overridden to validate the class variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume that i have a following  'demo' class:

```
class demo(object):
   class_variable = None
```

Now whenever some one sets the 'class_variable', i need to validate the value (e.g. class_variable can have only values of type 'str').

```
demo.class_variable = 15
# here int value is assigned, i want to raise exception for such cases
```

This can be done for the instance variables by overriding the **setattr**(self,f,v) method.

How can it be done for the class variables ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5189699/1126841 is a near-duplicate; I'm not confident enough that it solves the problem to vote to close myself.

Answer (score 2):

By defining the appropriate `__setattr__` on the metaclass for the class `demo`. As an example:

Create a MetaClass that defines the logic in its `__setattr__` method (might want to perform a check based on the `name` of the attribute:

```
class DemoMeta(type):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return super(DemoMeta, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Only str values allowed")
```

Define a class which uses this meta class:

```
class demo(object):
    __metaclass__ = DemoMeta
    class_variable = None
```

And now, when you try to assign to `class_variable` a value that is not an instance of a string, `DemoMeta.__setattr__` is going to get called, check and validate the assignment.

```
demo.class_variable = 12
```

Raises:

```
ValueError: Only str values allowed
```

Comment: How would this be achieved in python 3? Copying the above does not raise the ValueError.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Change the `demo` class from `class demo(object): ...` to `class demo(metaclass=MetaDemo): ...` and remove the `__metaclass__` since it makes no difference.