# How to define a static, and yet dynamic, property in a base class?

Tags: python, oop, properties

I have a base class and some subclasses that inherit from it. On these subclasses, I define a static property. I'd like to define another static property in the base class whose value is based on the subclass's static property's value.

Here is a toy example of what I'm referring to:

Imagine I have a few constants defined somewhere:

```
SERVICE_ID_TACO_BELL = 1
SERVICE_ID_T_MOBILE = 2
SERVICE_NAMES = {
    SERVICE_ID_TACO_BELL: "Taco Bell",
    SERVICE_ID_T_MOBILE: "T-Mobile",
}
```

And then I want to define my base class and some sub classes:

```
class BaseService(object):
    service_id = None

    @classmethod
    def get_service_name(cls):
        return SERVICE_NAMES.get(cls.service_id)


class TacoBell(BaseService):
    service_id = SERVICE_ID_TACO_BELL
```

Right now we can do this:

```
assert TacoBell.service_id == SERVICE_ID_TACO_BELL
assert TacoBell.get_service_name() == "Taco Bell"
```

The goal is to be able to do this:

```
assert TacoBell.service_name == "Taco Bell"
```

We can do something like this after the fact:

```
setattr(TacoBell, 'service_name', TacoBell.get_service_name())
```

but that feels messy

How can we add a static, yet dynamic property to `BaseService` that checks the subclass's `service_id` property against `SERVICE_NAMES` to return the value?

I have a feeling that the solution is metaclasses.

Comment: This looks needlessly complicated; why so many layers of indirection?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static, yet dynamic"?

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191224/9225671)