# How to input-check a class property

Tags: python, class, class-properties

I have a certain class `MyClass` with a class attribute `SOMETHING`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    SOMETHING = 12
```

I would like `SOMETHING` to be enforced to meet a certain condition, e.g. `SOMETHING < 100`.
How could I do that?

Ultimately, this class is meant to be subclassed by the user, e.g.:

```
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    SOMETHING = 13
```

---

I have been looking into the *class-property* approaches outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property), but they all seem to not play nicely with defining the property in the `class` body.

For example:

```
class MyClassMeta(type):
    _SOMETHING = 0

    @property
    def SOMETHING(cls):
        return cls._SOMETHING

    @SOMETHING.setter
    def SOMETHING(cls, something):
        if something < 100:
            cls._SOMETHING = something
        else:
            raise ValueError('SOMETHING must be < 100')


class MyClass(object, metaclass=MyClassMeta):
    # this is ignored
    SOMETHING = 100


x = MyClass()
print(MyClass.SOMETHING)
# 0
print(type(x).SOMETHING)
# 0
```

However, if the attribute is accessed *normally*, e.g.:

```
MyClass.SOMETHING = 50
print(MyClass.SOMETHING)
# 50
print(type(x).SOMETHING)
# 50
```

it works fine, even with subclassing:

```
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    SOMETHING = 40


y = MySubClass()
print(MySubClass.SOMETHING)
# 50
print(type(y).SOMETHING)
# 50
```

except that setting `SOMETHING` in the subclass is also ignored.

So, how could I trigger the execution of the `@SOMETHING.setter` code when `SOMETHING` is defined in the body of the `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following simple *metaclass* implementation to validate class 
 specific attributes on *declaration* phase:

```
class MyClassMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        if clsdict['SOMETHING'] >= 100:  # validate specific attribute value
            raise ValueError(f'{clsname}.SOMETHING should be less than 100')
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyClassMeta):
    SOMETHING = 12


class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    SOMETHING = 100
```

Running throws:

```
ValueError: MyChildClass.SOMETHING should be less than 100
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: Thanks! I was looking into `__new__` as a possible way to solve this, but the official documentation was just insufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Use two underlines to save the propertie  access from outside.
Second: If you inherit from the base class the property is still available. No need for new defining it.

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain yourself a bit better? I really do not see how this answer my question.

Comment: @MarLei : You are correct. Can you please write a clear answer ?
In brief, you just need to replace "_SOMETHING" by "__SOMETHING" (add an underscore) and your problem is solved

Comment: @ma3oun can you show this in a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378372/how-to-input-check-a-class-property)? I am 100% positive that changing a custom name everywhere (a.k.a. [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)) in any Python code **should not** affect code execution, but if you happen to discover something like this, it should be reported as a bug **immediately**.

Comment: The example I had in mind works for object attributes, not class variables. Sorry about the confusion