# Storing collection information in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

I have a `ModelManager` which keeps track of creating and destroying new objects. Here's an example:

```
class ModelManager:
    MAX_OBJECTS = 10
    OBJECTS = {} # hash to model object
    NUM_OBJECTS = len(OBJECTS) # how to dynamically calculate this?
```

Every time an object is created it is added to `OBJECTS` and everytime it is deleted it gets popped from `OBJECTS`.

How would I properly do the `NUM_OBJECTS` here? Ideally it should be a classmethod/property to act as a calculation. For doing something like the above, what would be the best way?

I would like to call it as `ModelManager.NUM_OBJECTS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed [`property`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

```
class ModelManager:

    @property
    def NUM_OBJECTS(self):
        return len(self.OBJECTS)
```

Also, note that `OBJECTS` will be shared across your class instances because it is a dictionary initialized at class scope. The `NUM_OBJECT` property requires initializing the class. If you want `NUM_OBJECTS` to be a property of the class, use one of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property) for class properties.

If you would rather be able to call `len` around your class (in addition to `NUM_OBJECTS`) - you can *overkill* with metaclasses:

```
class ModelManagerMeta(type):

    def __len__(cls):
         return len(cls.OBJECTS)

    def NUM_OBJECTS(cls):
         return len(cls.OBJECTS)


class ModelManager(metaclass=ModelManagerMeta):

    MAX_OBJECTS = 10
    OBJECTS = {} # hash to model object
    ...
```

Comment: right, but then I'd need to call it as `ModelManager().NUM_OBJECTS`. I'm just using it as a class manager, so calling it as `ModelManager.NUM_OBJECTS`.

Comment: @David542: You'll have a much smoother experience if you don't try to make a class do an instance's job.

Comment: @user2357112 what would be a better way to do the above then?

Comment: Make an instance instead of using the class directly. You can make it a module-level global if you really want.

Comment: @user2357112 do you mean something like: `manager=ModelManager()` at the top, and then just use that?

Comment: @user2357112 is right. Otherwise, you will probably have to implement most of your "class" in the meta class above for it to work as desired. This code is confusing and an abuse of metaclasses (imo)

Comment: @David542: Pretty much.