# How to inherit a variable from another class

Tags: python

I have a code:

```
class read:
    a = 0
    c = write.c
    def get_num():
        a = 6
        return a


class write:
    c = 0 
    a = read.get_num()
    def do_num(self):
        b = read.get_num()
        self.c = 10
        return b

print(write.c)
```

Questions:

1. How to get solution for `print(write.c)` at the end `10` for `c`.
2. How to make variable `c` in line `3` equal to the `c = 0` in class `write`
3. How to make variable `c` in line `3` equal to the `c = 10` in class `write`

Comment: If you write your questions like this, you won't get your answer.

Comment: Post a code preview, not a URL to an image...

Comment: `self.c` should be `write.c` if you want to update the class attribute instead of an instance attribute.

Comment: You never call `do_num()`.

Comment: `c = write.c` won't work unless you define `write` before `read`.

Comment: This code does not do anything related to inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `do_num()` needs to set `write.c` rather than `self.c` so that it sets the class attribute rather than an instance attribute. And you need to call `no_num()`.

```
class write:
    c = 0 
    a = read.get_num()
    def do_num(self):
        b = read.get_num()
        write.c = 10
        return b

w = write()
w.do_num()
print(write.c)
```

2. You need to define the classes on the other order. You can't access `write.c` before the class is defined.

```
class write:
    c = 0 
    a = read.get_num()
    def do_num(self):
        b = read.get_num()
        write.c = 10
        return b

class read:
    a = 0
    c = write.c
    def get_num():
        a = 6
        return a
```

3. You need to make `read.c` a class property that reads the value of `write.c` whenever it's used. See [How to make a class property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property) for how to define a class property.

Comment: You also can't do `a = read.get_num()` before the `read` class is defined. Neither order works, so the classes should be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should consider here, I strongly recommend you take a close look at inheritance in python cause that is exactly what you are looking for. Always remember to stick to conventional naming patterns, hence your classes should be capitalized

```
class Write:
    c = 0 

    def do_num(self):
        b = read.get_num()
        self.c = 10
        return b

class Read:
    a = 0
    c = Write.c
    def get_num():
        a = 6
        return a
```

This will not work because on every turn you will be trying to reference a non existent class, meaning that what you have in your code, when you create class `Write` you reference the `Read` class which has not be cretaed yet and if you switch it up you have the exact same problem.

With that said i believe what would be a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish here would be using class attributes not class variables

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.c = c
        self.a = a

    def do_num(self):
        #some code

    def do_num(self):
       #some code

   write = Book(0, 10) #a=0 and c=10
   read = Book(10, 0) #a=10 and c=0
```

with this you can have various instances and variations of a and c without getting tangled in a web of inheritance needlessly. And since you are trying to work with the same variables and methods in both classes, there is no reason not to make it one class and use instances of that class instead

Comment: `class Read(Write)` really? A `Read` is a `Write`?

Comment: haha, i was trying to go along with his code but i've changed it up already cause it did not make much sense to me either. A read inheriting from a write... hahaha