# How to pass cls to property rather than self

Tags: python, class, properties, python-class

I know how to use property in case of instance variable

```
class A():
    _foo=3
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.foo
a = A()
print(a.foo)
```

it show _foo

```
3
```

but i don't know how to use property in case of class variable

```
class A():
    _foo=3
    @property
    def foo(cls):
        return cls._foo
print(A.foo)
```

it show property object not 3

```
<property object at 0x7fba8c19ea70>
```

how to generate class variable getter/setter?

I found a way in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property)

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    @property
    def thingy(cls):
        return cls._thingy

class Foo(object, metaclass=MetaFoo):
    _thingy = 23
    
print(Foo.thingy)
```

it show

```
23
```

but i want more simple ways.

Comment: If you want `print(A.foo)` gives you `3`, why not just use `foo=3` under your class definition? Using the `property` decorator seems a bit redundant. I don't get what you want to achieve here.

Comment: Because I do use setter not getter. And in foo.setter function, I want to assign cls._bar, cls._foobar, cls._etc as well as cls._foo.
In other words, I want when I change cls._foo, cls._bar, cls.foobar, cls.etc are changed also.