# Property of a self instance in Django Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, object-properties

recently i have created a model for storing some states in my DB. It's very simple i only store id and name.

```py
class PayType(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{0}] {1}".format(self.id, self.name)
```

Here you can see a migration where i insert default values in the DB.

```py
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stockmanager', '0023_pagotipo_remove_carrito_unidades_totales_and_more'),
    ]

    def insertPayType(apps, schema_editor):
        PayType = apps.get_model('stockmanager', 'PayType')
        PayType(name="Credit").save()
        PayType(name="Debit").save()
        PayType(name="Cash").save()

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(insertPayType)
    ]
```

As you can see, i'll have fixed rows in DB.
I'd like to add **properties** in the **PayType** Model, in order to have easy access the instances of the model. Like a static attribute in java.

```py
class PayType(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{0}] {1}".format(self.id, self.name)

    # I'm looking for something like this
    @property
    def CREDIT(self):
        return self.objects.get(id = 1)
    # I also tried with this, same result :(
    @property
    def DEBIT(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self, id = 2)
```

I tried to access in a diferent part of my code with this

```py
class Pay(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    pay_type = models.ForeignKey(PayType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Pay(
    order_id = order_id,
    value = 100,
    # I want this
    pay_type = Pay.CASH #Error line
).save()
```

The thing is that i receive this error

```
Cannot assign "<property object at 0x00000138FEAC7F60>": "Pay.pay_type" must be a "PayType" instance.
```

Any idea?

Comment: add some print statements... but you could probably just do `CREDIT=1`  I think its smart enough to recognize it as a foreign key ... but you might need to do `pay_type_id=1` in your create test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a class property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property) Note the [answer by Barney Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055258/14991864) which uses [classproperty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.classproperty) from Django

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just write your logic this way? It should work as indeed:

```
# I'm looking for something like this
    @property
    def CREDIT(self):
        return PayType.objects.get(id = 1)
    # I also tried with this, same result :(
    @property
    def DEBIT(self):
        return get_object_or_404(PayType, id = 2)
```

You could also try to fetch `PayType` class using meta framework or try to catch it using `type(self)`, I think it should work.

Comment: Same error ```Cannot assign "<property object at 0x00000138FE88860>": "Pay.pay_type" must be a "PayType" instance.
```

Comment: After a lot of thinking and searching, it seems to me that this is my mistake and as you say, it would be necessary to change the logic of the program.