Can I create an immutable class attribute in Python 3?
I am writing a class with custom __eq__ and __hash__ methods, and __hash__ basically returns one of class' attributes (which is an integer). Therefore, I need to make this attribute as immutable as possible. Is there a way to make an attribute immutable in Python?
I can, of course, make it __private, but that's not quite the same thing. Also at this point of time I am not sure if I should make my class a dataclass.
More context if this is somehow relevant: the class Simplex represents a combinatorial simplex, and stores a set of vertices (in the form of a binary number) and an integer coefficient. The class has a method boundary() that should return an object of the type Complex, which is a collection of Simplex instances. The __eq__ method thinks A == B   if their sets of vertices coincide (coefficients are not relevant). The method __hash__ returns the binary storing vertices. I want __hash__ to work in this specific way, because I think it would simplify adding up equal simplices in Complex.

The simple answer is "no". The recommended method for hiding something is __private.  But Python doesn't really have such a concept as a private variable, so the person running the program can always go digging around wherever they want.

Try to use a customized class_property decorator.
Something like (copy from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191224/24285005):

class ClassPropertyDescriptor(object):

    def __init__(self, fget, fset=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset

    def __get__(self, obj, klass=None):
        if klass is None:
            klass = type(obj)
        return self.fget.__get__(obj, klass)()

def classproperty(func):
    if not isinstance(func, (classmethod, staticmethod)):
        func = classmethod(func)

    return ClassPropertyDescriptor(func)


class Bar(object):
    @classproperty
    def bar(cls):
        return 1



Frank Yellin is entirely correct to say that Python doesn't have true private variables.
Python however does have the option to change the way attributes are accessed and edited, this can be utilised to change the way a class interacts with surrounding code, such as adding validation - one of the main reasons you might want an attribute to be private.
Below an example how to implement this through a getter @property and a setter @brand.setter decorator.
class GermanCar:
    def __init__(self, model, brand):
        self.model = model
        self.brand = brand

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The car brand is {self.brand} and the model is {self.model}"
    
    @property
    def brand(self):
        return self._brand
    
    @brand.setter
    def brand(self, brand):
        print(brand)
        if brand not in {"BMW", "Mercedes", "Volkswagen"}:
            raise ValueError(f"This class only allows German car brands, {brand} isn't.")
        self._brand = brand


def build_car():
    brand = input("Brand: ")
    model = input("Model: ")
    return GermanCar(model, brand)

car = build_car()
print(car)

The above has the advantage of separating the attribute users will interact with car.brand from the one that's used to store the value car._brand, thereby reducing the risks of accidental changes.
If you play around with this code you'll notice one can't change car.brand without going through the setter function - in which you can add any validation (including outright forbidding the edit).
This doesn't make it a truly immutable variable however, but simply another security layer. If someone really intends to break your code and wants to circumvent the validation, they could simply edit car._brand directly, circumventing the validation.
That's why the _private naming convention exists, even if it's just a warning sign that people can choose to ignore. The above can prevent most unintentional edits however.
