# Different behavior of a class-member which could be a type or a factory-function

Tags: python, inheritance, class-members

Whenever I define a class whose instances create objects of other classes, I like defining the types of those other objects as class members:

```
class Foo(object):
    DICT_TYPE = dict  # just a trivial example
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = self.DICT_TYPE()

class Bar(Foo):
    DICT_TYPE = OrderedDict  # no need to override __init__ now
```

The idea is to allow potential subclasses to easily override it.

I've just found a problem with this habbit, when the "type" I use is not really a type, but a factory function. For example, `RLock` is confusingly not a class:

```
def RLock(*args, **kwargs):
    return _RLock(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thus using it the same way is no good:

```
class Foo(object):
    LOCK_TYPE = threading.RLock  # alas, RLock() is a function...
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = self.LOCK_TYPE()
```

The problem here is that since `RLock` is a function, `self.LOCK_TYPE` gets bound to `self`, resulting with a bound-method, consequently leading to an error.

---

Here's a quick demonstration of how things go wrong when a function is used instead of a class (for a case simpler than `RLock` above):

```
def dict_factory():
    return {}

class Foo(object):
    DICT_TYPE1 = dict
    DICT_TYPE2 = dict_factory

f = Foo()
f.DICT_TYPE1()
=> {}
f.DICT_TYPE2()
=> TypeError: dict_factory() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

---

Does anybody have a good solution for this problem? Is my habbit of defining those class members fundamentally wrong?

I guess I could replace it with a factory method. Would that be a better approach?

```
class Foo(object);
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = self._make_lock()
    def _make_lock(self):
        return threading.RLock()
```

Comment: what error? I dont see an error ... I dont understand whats the problem...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I added more details about the error

Comment: I see ... now thats more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the staticmethod decorator to ensure your class does not get passed in

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     DICT_TYPE = staticmethod(my_dict)
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.DICT_TYPE()
{}
```

Comment: That's clever, but inellegant. I'm looking for a solution which works for both classes and functions.

Comment: it should work fine ... all it does is not put self in the arguments ... list ... it is much more elegant than your class property ... since that still passes `cls` ... but meh glad to hear you have it working ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be bypassed by using a `classproperty` (e.g. as defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203659/2096752)):

```
class Foo(object):
    @classproperty
    def DICT_TYPE(cls):
        return dict_factory
```