# Is it a good idea to use property getter as constant variable for a class

Tags: python

Since Python has no const type. I have some attributes in a class that I do not wish to be modified.

So is it a good idea to define the attributes as property and only give it a getter without a setter? If not what is the issue?

```
class Aclass:
    def __init__(self):
        # do some init

    @property
    def constA(self):
        return 'abc'
```

Many thanks.

J

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It can only be called from instances, not from the class which seems semantically questionable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203286/how-to-create-a-read-only-class-property-in-python/26634248 for a different approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

> This [`@property`] makes it possible to create read-only properties easily using `property()` as a decorator.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that. The conventional code looks like this:

```py
class Aclass:
    def __init__(self):
        # the underscore implies that the attribute is private
        self._constA = 'abc'

    @property
    def constA(self):
        return self._constA
```