# python read-only class properties

Tags: python, properties

Is there a way to make read-only class properties in Python? Ex. in Unity3d you can do this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.zero
```

Vector3.zero returns an instance of the Vector3 class where x, y, and z are 0. This is basically the same as:

```
transform.position = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
class Vector3(object):
    zero = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    ...
```

But I get an undefined variable error because the class hasn't been defined yet. So how do you make read-only class properties that don't require an instance of the class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a metaclass

```
class MetaVector3(type):

    @property
    def zero(cls):
        return cls(0,0,0)

class Vector3(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaVector3

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

>>> v = Vector3.zero
>>> v.x, v.y, v.z
(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Metaclasses can't be multiply inherited or composed, so if you want another metaclass ever, or another superclass, you're SOL. I generally avoid them.

Comment: Metaclasses can be very useful, but one certainly doesn't seem like the appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: @Devin -- that's a self defeating argument. You get no value from metaclasses if you never use them. Even if you could only ever use one metaclass, you'd get some value -- more than if you don't use them at all just because you can't use multiple ones in some situations. eryksun, beautiful answer as always.

Comment: @agf Implicit in "I avoid them" was "unless they are necessary". This is not such a case, as there are other things that produce identical behavior but don't involve metaclasses (in particular, descriptors).

Comment: An additional benefit of this method is that the `zero` property won't appear on instances.

Comment: This works well enough for my purposes: creating a `Constants` class.

Answer (score 10):

The most obvious way might be to alter the class object after the fact:

```
class Vector3(object):
    # ...
Vector3.zero = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
```

The main problem with this is that there's then only one zero object, and if it's mutable you can cause accidental damage all over the place. It may be easier (and feel less hacky) to use a dynamic descriptor that creates a zero vector every time it's accessed (this is done by creating a [ClassProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods) class):

```
class ClassProperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()

class Vector3(object):
    @ClassProperty
    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        return cls(0, 0, 0)
```

---

I consider none of these really "pythonic", though. Consider the other mathematical types in Python: ints, floats, and complex numbers. None of these have a "zero" class attribute, or a zero constructor, instead they return zero when called with no arguments. So perhaps it might be best to do like so:

```
class Vector3(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

This is less like Unity3D and more like Python, if you know what I mean.

Comment: The first answer is the obvious one, but then it's not read-only. The second one requires an instance of the class in order to use the property. The third one doesn't really do what I want it to do. I'm more looking for the way Unity made it work.

Comment: @topher fixed, but it's strange to code things in a way that are alien to the environment. Python classes don't usually work this way.

Comment: @topher, In Python, we don't habitually enforce things like read-only at a programatic level. If you don't give someone any reason to reassign this value and they don't have malicious intent, they won't do so. If they are out to do bad things, you can't help them by doing the special-descriptor/metaclass thing.

Comment: *"Consider the other mathematical types in Python: ints, floats, and complex numbers. None of these have a "zero" class attribute, or a zero constructor, instead they return zero when called with no arguments."* This is a fantastic insight.

Comment: @Mike, I also want to have class properties for the unit vectors i, j, and k. So adding defaults in the init function isn't what I'm looking for. But the class property is really close, it's just not read-only.

Comment: @topher, Your insistence on read-only-ness is misplaced. This *is* nominally read-only and additionally I could quite easily change it with the metaclass solution. *In Python, trying to enforce things like "read only" at a language level is a waste of effort.*

Comment: @topher, The fact that there might be other constants of interest does not really impact the implementation of your zero, a thing for which Devin recommends a way with *tons* of precedent. As a remark in the same vein, `Vector3(y=1)` might prove nicer than `Vector3.j`.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors):

```
class Zero(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return owner(0, 0, 0)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        #could raise an exception here or somethiing
        #this gets called if the user attempts to overwrite the property
        pass  

class Vector3(object):
    zero = Zero()

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
```

Should do what you want:

```
>>> v = Vector3(1, 2, 3)
>>> v
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> v.zero
{'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}
>>> v.zero = 'foo'
>>> v.zero
{'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Comment: I believe that the `owner` parameter in descriptor's `__get__` method is the owning class, so that can be rewritten as `return owner(0, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're imagining is possible, but not necessary in this case. Just wait until after your class is defined to assign the attribute

```
class Vector3(object):
    ...
Vector3.zero = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
```

or make it a module level constant.

---

There is a good chance you want simply to use a shape `(3,)` numpy array instead of writing this class, for any practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really interesting question, the workaround I would go with is to do a classmethod as a "getter" for the zero object:

```
class Vector3(object):
    __zero = None
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        if not cls.__zero:
            cls.__zero = Vector3(0,0,0) 
        return cls.__zero

myzerovec = Vector3.zero()
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but this is a method. Is there a way to make this a class property?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, aside from the metaclass answer above, but that causes zero to actually return a different Vector3 instance each time you refer to it, which I don't think is what you wanted (a single statically defined object).  Honestly though is it really that big of a difference doing "Vector3.zero()" as opposed to "Vector3.zero"?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassProperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()

class Vector3(object):
    _zero = None

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    @ClassProperty
    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        if cls._zero is None:
            cls._zero = cls(0,0,0) 
        return cls._zero
```

Shamelessly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods)

Comment: Take a closer look at Devin's answer, he already posted this before you.

Comment: @agf: I saw it, but you can notice he edited his answer (see [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7273347/revisions)) and it wasn't like that when I started writing my answer. Thanks for pointing it out anyway...

Answer (score -1):

As for the read-only part, [this](http://www.bright-green.com/blog/2004_06_03/read_only_python_attributes.html) is a good resource.

```
template = property(lambda self: self.__template)
```