# python class properties

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm trying to find the best way to extend a class variable.  Hopefully an example of the method I've come up with so far will make this clear.

```
class A(object):
    foo = ['thing', 'another thing']

class B(A):
    foo = A.foo + ['stuff', 'more stuff']
```

So I'm trying to make the subclass inherit and extend the parent's class variable.  The method above works, but seems a bit kludgey.  I'm open to any suggestion, including accomplishing something similar using a completely different approach.

Obviously I can continue to use this method if need be, but if there's a better way I'd like to find it.

Comment: What is it about `foo` that it needs to be a [class property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/) and not just an instance property? (For that matter, given that lists are mutable, you can *change* the class property at `__init__` time.)

Comment: IMHO, what you have looks fine to me (and I can't think of a more clean way to do it).  By the way, I would call these "class attributes", not "class properties" as a property is something different (usually created by the `property` builtin function/decorator).

Comment: @kojiro He's not referring to those kind of properties, he just means attributes.

Comment: The main reason I am avoiding initializing it as an instance variable in __init__ is code cleanliness.  If I don't need __init__ for any other purpose, I prefer to avoid writing one, along with the (IMO) ugly super()__init__() call just to initialize one variable.

Comment: IMO, the way shown above is completely clean. A static variable is bound to a class. When inheriting, a new static variable would be bound to the most child class. Redefining it makes it clear that you also have a static foo in B. Besides that, this mostly looks like a design issue to me since this "pattern" it is not just very uncommon but also not a real inheritance pattern.

Comment: I would also say that the way you have it is good. It is practiced everywhere and makes the purpose very obvious.

Answer (score 8):

Could use a metaclass:

```
class AutoExtendingFoo(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        foo = []
        for base in bases:
           try:
               foo.extend(getattr(base, 'foo'))
           except AttributeError:
               pass
        try:
            foo.extend(attrs.pop('foo_additions'))
        except KeyError:
            pass
        attrs['foo'] = foo
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = AutoExtendingFoo
    foo_additions = ['thing1', 'thing2']
    # will have A.foo = ['thing1', 'thing2']

class B(A):
    foo_additions = ['thing3', 'thing4']
    # will have B.foo = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']

class C(A):
    pass
    # will have C.foo = ['thing1', 'thing2']

class D(B):
    pass
    # will have D.foo = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']
```

Comment: Nice, but violates principle of least surprise. Maybe assign to `__add_to_foo__`, instead, pretending that we inherit an empty `foo` from `object`.

Answer (score 1):

I definitively would go for instance-properties. *(if I got it right, they are not bound to be static for your case?!)*

```
>>> class A:
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         return ['thin', 'another thing']
...
>>> class B(A):
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         return super().foo + ['stuff', 'thing 3']
...
>>> B().foo
['thin', 'another thing', 'stuff', 'thing 3']
```

Comment: That's not particularly efficient if you access this data frequently.  You have to do an attribute lookup on `A` then create a new list and append to it every time you access `B.foo`.  Plus you still have the problem that every subclass has to define the property such that it retrieves `super().foo`.  And if any future classes inherit from multiple foo-having classes, you start getting lots of hard to follow problems fast.