# python Override inner Meta class attribute

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: This has nothing to do with django. I have only tagged it Django because django has a very similar object structure, and the knowledge might be exchangeable.

I am using the cement cli framework and am trying to change the usage statement. This is more of a python inheritance question than a cement question. Here is an example of what I have:

```
class AbstractBaseController(controller.CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        usage = 'foo ' + label + ' [options. .]'

class BarController(AbstractBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'bar'
```

Now, let me explain what is going on here. I have multiple controllers (more than just the bar controller) and I want them all to inherit the usage attribute from the AbstractBaseController.Meta, however, I want the usage statement to use the new label, not the Abstract label. **The main goal here is to get the usage statement to work on every controller without having to copy and paste it into every controller**. Right now, the usage is inherited as `'foo base [options. .]'` as it does not replace label before making the substitution.

I have tried the following:

```
class AbstractBaseController(controller.CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        usage = 'foo {cmd} [options. .]'

class BarController(AbstractBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'bar'
        usage = AbstractBaseController.Meta.usage.replace('{cmd}', label)
```

And this works. However, I still have the copy and paste issue, since I have to copy this usage cmd into every controller.

I have also tried this:

```
class AbstractBaseController(controller.CementBaseController):
    class Meta:
        label = 'base'
        usage = 'foo {cmd} [options. .]'
        def __init__(self):
            self.usage = 'foo ' + self.label + ' [options]'

class BarController(AbstractBaseController):
    class Meta(AbstractBaseController.Meta):
        label = 'bar'
```

But that doesnt seem to do anything. Even with the `__init__` I still get `usage = 'foo {cmd}'` and not even `usage = 'foo base'`

Is there anyway to get the usage statement unique with the label for each controller while having the code reside in only one place? (The abstract controller)

Comment: Hi Nick, Any success?

Comment: @Nihar no, I never did figure this out, but it's been a while and upon second look, I think xavier's solution should work. I would need to dive a little into cement code to see why it wasn't working, but for non cement stuff, this sounds like it would work. Are you using cement or just trying to override a meta? My guess is cement never intatiates the class, it just does a class look up, `Meta.usage ` instead of `Meta().usage`

Comment: Using a class property is probably the right solution. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a method?

```
class A : 
    class SubA:
        label = 'base'
        def __init__(self) :
            self.usage = 'foo '+self.label+' [options]'
class B() :
    class SubB(A.SubA) :
        label = 'bar'

a = A().SubA()
b = B().SubB()
print(a.usage) # "foo base [options]"
print(b.usage) # "foo bar [options]"
```

Comment: The framework calls X.Meta.usage. And I need to pass the information to the framework, so just making a method doesnt work.

Comment: So if usage needs to be set as a variable you're going to need a constructor.  I edited  the code to illustrate this.

Comment: Tried that with no avail. I will add it to my question.