# Python Class Name as Class Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-variables

I'm working as an application with classes and subclasses. For each class, both super and sub, there is a class variable called `label`. I would like the `label` variable for the super class to default to the class name. For example:

```
class Super():
    label = 'Super'

class Sub(Super):
    label = 'Sub'
```

Rather than manually type out the variable for each class, is it possible to derive the variable from the class name in the super class and have it automatically populated for the subclasses?

```
class Super():
    label = # Code to get class name

class Sub(Super)
    pass
    # When inherited Sub.label == 'Sub'.
```

The reason for this is that this will be the default behavior. I'm also hoping that if I can get the default behavior, I can override it later by specifying an alternate `label`.

```
class SecondSub(Super):
    label = 'Pie'  # Override the default of SecondSub.label == 'SecondSub'
```

I've tried using `__name__`, but that's not working and just gives me `'__main__'`.

I would like to use the class variable `label` in `@classmethod` methods. So I would like to be able to reference the value without having to actually create a Super() or Sub() object, like below:

```
class Super():
    label = # Magic

    @classmethod
    def do_something_with_label(cls):
        print(cls.label)
```

Comment: you should have specified that you needed it to work with uninstantiated classes. you would have gotten a more correct solution sooner

Comment: You are right, I should have. Will fix that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A metaclass might be useful here.

```
class Labeller(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        dct.setdefault('label', name)
        return super(Labeller, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

# Python 2
# class Super(object):
#    __metaclass__ = Labeller

class Super(metaclass=Labeller):
    pass

class Sub(Super):
    pass

class SecondSub(Super):
    label = 'Pie'

class ThirdSub(SecondSub):
    pass
```

Disclaimer: when providing a custom metaclass for your class, you need to make sure it is compatible with whatever metaclass(es) are used by any class in its ancestry. Generally, this means making sure your metaclass inherits from all the other metaclasses, but it can be nontrivial to do so. In practice, metaclasses aren't so commonly used, so it's usually just a matter of subclassing `type`, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Could you point to some explanation about why `super(Labeller, meta)` must be used instead of just `super()`?

Comment: Python 3 introduced the ability of `super` to be used without explicit arguments; I am more accustomed to Python 2, and added the arguments out of habit.

Answer (score 10):

you can return `self.__class__.__name__` in label as a property

```
class Super:
    @property
    def label(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

class Sub(Super):
   pass

print Sub().label
```

alternatively you could set it in the `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self):
    self.label = self.__class__.__name__
```

this will obviously only work on instantiated classes

to access the class name inside of a class method you would need to just call `__name__` on the `cls`

```
class XYZ:
    @classmethod
    def my_label(cls):
        return cls.__name__

print XYZ.my_label()
```

this solution might work too  (snagged from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624858/541038)

```
class classproperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
    def __get__(self, owner_self, owner_cls):
        return self.fget(owner_cls)

class Super(object): 
    @classproperty
    def label(cls):
        return cls.__name__

class Sub(Super):
   pass

print Sub.label  #works on class
print Sub().label #also works on an instance

class Sub2(Sub):
   @classmethod
   def some_classmethod(cls):
       print cls.label

Sub2.some_classmethod()
```

Comment: I was just running to ipython to try a dir(self) inside a class when you added the answer. Bravo! I learned something new!

Comment: Would I be able to reference that instance property again inside of a @classmethod?

Comment: @user2004245 `self.__class__` can only be evaluated *after* the class has been completely defined, so you can get the label at run-time but not at design time of the class (so you can use it *inside* of a method, but not as a value of a class attribute).

Comment: Using `__init__` would establish that as an instance variable, I specifically need it as a class variable so that it can be referenced in @classmethod.

Comment: You'll probably want to make this a custom descriptor instead of a property, so it shows up properly when you do `Super.label` instead of just working on instances. Depending on whether `label = whatever` in `SecondSub` should be inherited by `class ThirdSub(SecondSub)`, it might also be worth making it a data descriptor and checking the class dict for overrides yourself.

Comment: you never specified that you needed it in a @classmethod (not sure why you need it in a @classmethod ...  since you can just access `cls.__name__`

Comment: added a solution that makes it available at the classmethod level

Comment: Never mind about the data descriptor thing - I forgot that those only override the instance dict, not subclass dicts.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class ClassNameDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        return type_.__name__

class Super(object):
    label = ClassNameDescriptor()

class Sub(Super):
    pass

class SecondSub(Super):
    label = 'Foo'
```

Demo:

```
>>> Super.label
'Super'
>>> Sub.label
'Sub'
>>> SecondSub.label
'Foo'
>>> Sub().label
'Sub'
>>> SecondSub().label
'Foo'
```

If `class ThirdSub(SecondSub)` should have `ThirdSub.label == 'ThirdSub'` instead of `ThirdSub.label == 'Foo'`, you can do that with a bit more work. Assigning `label` at the class level will be inherited, unless you use a metaclass (which is a lot more hassle than it's worth for this), but we can have the `label` descriptor look for a `_label` attribute instead:

```
class ClassNameDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        try:
            return type_.__dict__['_label']
        except KeyError:
            return type_.__name__
```

Demo:

```
>>> class SecondSub(Super):
...     _label = 'Foo'
...
>>> class ThirdSub(SecondSub):
...     pass
...
>>> SecondSub.label
'Foo'
>>> ThirdSub.label
'ThirdSub'
```

Comment: great answer and you beat my edit that does this as well (+1 from me good sir :) )

Comment: There is a certain asymmetry here, though. `SecondSub.label` is an actual string, no longer a descriptor. A class such as `class ThirdSub(SecondSub): pass` would have a label of "Foo", not "ThirdSub".

Comment: @chepner: Working on that.

Comment: Nice. A metaclass is more elegant, but this is easier to use if another metaclass (like `ABCMeta`) is already in use in the class hierarchy.

Comment: @chepner: That's the kind of thing that makes me consider the metaclass more hassle than it's worth for this. Two unrelated descriptors mix just fine; two unrelated metaclasses produces a TypeError. If someone wants to mix-in `collections.Sequence` or something like that in a subclass, I'd prefer to let them.

Comment: PEP-487 aims at providing a simpler way of customizing classes, using a new magic method rather than a metaclass. Once accepted, it would be useful for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.6, the cleanest way to achieve this is with `__init_subclass__` hook introduced in [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/). It is much simpler (and easier to manage with respect to inheritance) than using a metaclass.

```py
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if 'label' not in cls.__dict__:  # Check if label has been set in the class itself, i.e. not inherited from any of its superclasses
            cls.label = cls.__name__  # If not, default to class's __name__

class Sub1(Base):
    pass
    
class Sub2(Base):
    label = 'Custom'

class SubSub(Sub2):
    pass

print(Sub1.label)    # Sub1
print(Sub2.label)    # Custom
print(SubSub.label)  # SubSub
```