# Is there a dedicated way to get the number of items in a python `Enum`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Say I have such a python `Enum` class:

```
from enum import Enum

class Mood(Enum):
    red = 0
    green = 1
    blue = 2
```

Is there a natural way to get the total number of items in `Mood`? (like without having to iterate over it, or to add an extra `n` item, or an extra `n` [`classproperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624858/3719101), *etc*.)

Does the `enum` module provide such a functionality?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes.  `Enum`s have several extra abilities that normal classes do not:

```
class Example(Enum):
    this = 1
    that = 2
    dupe = 1
    those = 3

print(len(Example))  # duplicates are not counted
# 3

print(list(Example))
# [<Example.this: 1>, <Example.that: 2>, <Example.those: 3>]

print(Example['this'])
# Example.this

print(Example['dupe'])
# Example.this

print(Example(1))
# Example.this
```

Comment: My enum (Python 3.4) is not static but created as presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695250/150978) (the one form automatic enumeration) and the last three commands do not work for such an enum. Are there different enum-implementations in Python?

Comment: There is a third-party library called `enum` that is **not** the same as the official 3.4 `Enum`, nor it's [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) and [advanced](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) versions.  Whatever `enum` you are using is not one of the three new ones.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try `print(len(Mood))` ?