# How to allow sting initialization for enums in pybind?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

In Python, I can initialize an enum from a string using standard construction:

```
class A(Enum):
  A = 'a'
a = A('a')
```

This is helpful for reading configurations from external files.

However, once I move this enum to C++ and bind it with pybind, `__init__()` can only accept ints...

Is there an option to bind a custom initializer to the binded enum so that the string-initializer syntax `A('a')` will still work?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#enumerations-and-internal-types

Comment: @TooTone can you be more specific? I couldn't find an answer in the docs

Comment: The problem is that in your Python example, the enumerated value is a string, which is why that constructor works. Had it been an integer, you wouldn't be able to do that. And C++ doesn't support enumerations with string values.

Comment: That said, if you want to have an enumeration of integers and add a way to construct their instances by passing in a string representing the name of the enumerated value (in this case it would have to be `A('A')``... that wouldn't be too difficult to do. There's already a dictionary mapping names to values (I mention it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682936/3962537)), so you could implement some factory function even in pure Python.