# How to make class atrribute separate per each class to avoid overwrite from different classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Simple example Parent is class with version attribute. I want to inherit from this class but avoid sharing versions attribute among all inherited classes.

```
class Parent(object):
    versions = []

    @classmethod
    def add_version(cls, version):
        cls.versions.append(version)

class P1(Parent):
    pass

class P2(Parent):
    pass

class Thing(object):
    pass

P1.add_version(Thing)
# should be Thing
print(P1.versions)
# should be empty [] by my design but it works other way in Python
# how to achieve to different versions fields without coding it in child classes?
print(P2.versions)
```

Produce such result since version is shared between classes - how to avoid?

```
[<class '__main__.Thing'>]
[<class '__main__.Thing'>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically you dont *need* a metaclass - a simple class decorator also works (well, kind of...):

```
def versions_container(cls):
    if "versions" not in cls.__dict__:
        print("adding versions to class {}".format(cls.__name__))
        cls.versions = []
    return cls


@versions_container # this one is useless but anyway...
class Parent(object):
    versions = []
    @classmethod
    def add_version(cls, version):
        cls.versions.append(version)

@versions_container
class P1(Parent):
    pass

@versions_container
class P2(Parent):
    pass

class Thing(object):
    pass

P1.add_version(Thing)
print(P1.versions)
print(P2.versions)
```

**but** this is barely better than manually adding the `versions` attribute in each child class.

The custom metaclass solution is not such a big deal and will make sure users of your code won't break the expectations:

```
class VersionsContainer(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        if "versions" not in attrs:
            attrs["versions"] = []
        return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)

class Parent(object, metaclass=VersionContainer):
    @classmethod
    def add_version(cls, version):
        cls.versions.append(version)

class P1(Parent):
    pass

class P2(Parent):
    pass

class Thing(object):
    pass

P1.add_version(Thing)
print(P1.versions)
print(P2.versions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redeclare `versions` in each child class:

```
class P1(Parent):
    versions = []

class P2(Parent):
    versions = []
```

The only way to avoid doing this would be to use metaclasses, which is far more hassle than you need.

Comment: Good idea but maybe there more simpler solution but you are right metaclass is need.

Comment: " which is far more hassle than you need" => well, depends on the context. If that's for a couple child classes living in the same module and none of these classes are expected to be extended by someone else then yes indeed, just manually adding the `versions` attribute is the obvious solution. Now if it's library or framework code and `Parent` is supposed to be extended by the library or framework user then the five lines metaclass is really worth the "hassle" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the versions as class attributes of each class, you can store them all in one dict.

```
class Parent(object):

    _versions = {}  # class -> version_list

    @classproperty
    def versions(cls):
        return cls._versions.setdefault(cls, [])

    @classmethod
    def add_version(cls, version):
        cls.versions.append(version)

class P1(Parent):
    pass
class P2(Parent):
    pass

P1.add_version(1)
print(P1.versions)
print(P2.versions)
```

(`classproperty` is a very useful non-builtin construct. You can find it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624858/2096752))

I'm not neccessarily saying this is the best or most elegant approach, but it is really simple and avoids metaclasses, etc.  The clear disadvantage of this approach is that it requires a class to store data for its subclasses, which is not great design-wise.

Comment: I do not know classproperty it looks like the best answer. I will try to do little different code.