# property decorator which functions on class (as opposed to instance) , setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties, python-decorators

Property decorators are discussed at length in the documentation and the machinery which resolves them is discussed as well, *but only for getters*. I have been entirely unsuccessful in making a setter work **for an uninstantiated class**. Simple example:

**My Property Decorator**

```
class ClassyProp(object):

    """ Classmethod + property """

    def __init__(self, input_func):
        log(f"ClassProp.__init__({input_func})")
        self.func = input_func

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        log(f"ClassProp.__get__({obj}, {cls})")
        return self.func

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        log("__ClassyProp__.__set__()")

    def setter(self, fset):
        log("__ClassyProp__.setter()")

    def fset(*args):
        log("__ClassyProp__.fset()")
```

**Test Class**

```
class foo(object):
    """ Test class """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @ClassyProp
    def f(cls):
        """ Test property_lazy_static get , set """
        pass
```

**Run**

```
print("======== ObjFoo ========")

ObjFoo = foo()
print(ObjFoo.f)
ObjFoo.f = 18
print(ObjFoo.f)

print("======== class foo ========")

print(foo.f)
foo.f = 15
print(foo.f)
```

**Yields**

```
[      00s] ClassProp.__init__(<function foo.f at 0x7f4330c88268>)
======== ObjFoo ========
[      00s] ClassProp.__get__(<__main__.foo object at 0x7f4351522748>, <class '__main__.foo'>)
<function foo.f at 0x7f4330c88268>
[      00s] __ClassyProp__.__set__()
[      00s] ClassProp.__get__(<__main__.foo object at 0x7f4351522748>, <class '__main__.foo'>)
<function foo.f at 0x7f4330c88268>
======== class foo ========
[      00s] ClassProp.__get__(None, <class '__main__.foo'>)
<function foo.f at 0x7f4330c88268>
15
```

**NOTE**: If I had `ClassyProp` return values it wouldn't say the function id, does say proper values for get, but I just wanted print outs for the purpose of debugging.

As you can see, the getter AND setter is called properly for the Instance of `ObjFoo`. But not for the uninstantiated class `foo`. Is having a property setter simply not possible on classes? The documentation states (I added breaks):

> For objects, the machinery is in
>    - object.**getattribute**() which transforms b.x into
>    - type(b).**dict**['x'].**get**(b, type(b))
>
> The implementation works through a precedence chain that
>    - gives data descriptors priority over instance variables,
>    - instance variables priority over non-data descriptors, and
>    - assigns lowest priority to **getattr**() if provided.

*and*

> For classes, the machinery is in:
>      - type.**getattribute**() which transforms B.x into
>      - B.**dict**['x'].**get**(None, B)

With no mention of `__set__` for either. (**get** obviously is working for both the class and the instance)

So I am left wondering now, is this possible? I see nothing in the documentation suggesting it isn't, but all testing suggests this.

Comment: "I am left wondering now, is this possible? " What is possible? Intercepting a set on a class property?

Comment: That ^ thread is a little outdated, but it answers your question nonetheless. I recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800999/1222951) answer. Just keep in mind that the syntax for using a metaclass has changed in python 3 (You now have to do `class foo(metaclass=MyMetaClass):`).

Comment: Also, while it doesn't explicitly answer your question about how descriptors are resolved, [here's](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) the relevant documentation. They use `__get__` as an example, but I think it works the same way for `__set__` and `__delete__`.

Comment: Despite the other threading having being set for Python 2.2, it is still all true. You will need a metaclass, the answers there provide several examples. Just be sure to use the proper Python 3 syntax to use the metaclasses in your class.