# class variable (not instance variable) that is shortcut for object with type of same class?

Tags: python-3.x

> sorry for not perfect english (or some mistakes)! It isn't my native language.

some code that you need to see before answering my question.

```
class position:
    # position.zero is here.
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # or here
```

I need to make `position.zero` variable that is shortcut for `position(0, 0)` or `position()`

Comment: I'm not sure how useful a class variable will be. Why not just call `position()` instead of accessing `poistion.zero`? Is the value supposed to be changeable (so it only starts as `position(0,0)`, but could have a different value later)?

Comment: @Blckknght Value of `position.zero` won't be changeable, but i'll add some other shortcuts like `position.right` and `position.left`. There is method that "adds" two positions together and i think `position.left` or `position.right` will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a classmethod:

```
class position:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def zero(cls):
        return cls()
```

Making this into a property, so the interface is `position.zero` instead of `position.zero()`, is possible but non-trivial.  That is covered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128573/674039). If you only need/want one zero instance and you don't need it to respect inheritance, go for the simplest option available and just put it into the class namespace after definition:

```
class position:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

position.zero = position()
```