# How to use @property in models choices?

Tags: django, django-models

**My model:**

```
  class SomeModel(models.Model):
       ...
    models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BookPage.choices)**
```

**My choices:**

```
from enum import Enum


class BookPage(Enum):
    MAIN = "Main"
    SIDEBAR = "Sidebar"

    @property
    def choices(self):
        return [(key.value, key.name) for key in self]
```

**I got this error** Where I'm wrong?

```
choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).
```

Answer (score 2):

@d-malan is correct.  When you call a property from a class instead of an instance, it will just return the property method instead of actually calling it.  Using the `@classmethod` decorator will solve this.

Alternatively, if you are using a recent version of Django, you have two other options:

- Use the poorly-documented `classproperty` decorator [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/_modules/django/utils/functional/#classproperty].
- Use the `models.TextChoices` class (which has a built-in `choices` method) [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types]

Answer (score 1):

Your `choices` property is still an *instance* property so it won't give you your expected result when you call it on the `BookPage` class.

There doesn't [seem to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods) an easy way to create properties on classes.

I'd suggest rather just using a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod), e.g.:

```
class BookPage(Enum):
    MAIN = "Main"
    SIDEBAR = "Sidebar"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(key.value, key.name) for key in cls]
```

And call it as `BookPage.choices()`.