# Making A Class Constant Who's Type Is The Class In Which It Resides

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-class

I have a Python class with special values, "EMPTY" and "UNIVERSE":

```py
class RealSet:
    """Continuous open, half-open, and closed regions and discreet values of the Reals"""

    # implementation placeholder
    def __init__(self, intervals, *, canonicalize):
        pass

# Outside the class

RealSet.EMPTY = RealSet(tuple(), canonicalize=False)  # type: ignore
RealSet.UNIVERSE = RealSet(((None, None),), canonicalize=False)  # type: ignore
```

However, linting, code-completion, etc. don't like this because they're not seen as static attributes of the class. Even setting them is reported as a mypy error, hence the `# type: ignore`.

The below doesn't work because I can't construct a `RealSet` in the class scope because it doesn't exist yet:

```py
class RealSet:
    """Continuous open, half-open, and closed regions and discreet values of the Reals"""
    ...
    ...

    EMPTY = RealSet(tuple(), canonicalize=False)  # error
    UNIVERSE = RealSet(((None, None),), canonicalize=False)  # error
```

And this doesn't work because it defines instance attributes, not class attributes:

```py
class RealSet:
    """Continuous open, half-open, and closed regions and discreet values of the Reals"""
    ...
    ...

    EMPTY: "RealSet"
    UNIVERSE: "RealSet"

# Outside the class

RealSet.EMPTY = RealSet(tuple(), canonicalize=False)
RealSet.UNIVERSE = RealSet(((None, None),), canonicalize=False)
```

This seems to be a corner case in the design of Python classes. How can I make class attributes where the attribute's type is the class in which it resides? Bonus: make them constant.

Comment: Are you aware of `Enum`?

Comment: how are you planning to use this class? What is your use case?

Comment: @PeterWood Interesting. I'm not, but I think it would suffer from the same problem as the second code block. RealSet doesn't exist yet inside the class.

Comment: @iurii_n The typical things you might expect, but also some operations that I haven't found in existing implementations. For instance, taking an array as input and returning the indices of the elements that the set contains in O(n log n).

Comment: @Brent did you consider using @classmethod?

Comment: Would @classmethod give it attribute semantics?

Comment: it could build you objects, it's like a factory method

Comment: A @staticproperty of sorts could work

Comment: Python 3.9 only, but here we go https://stackoverflow.com/a/64738850/395029

Comment: @Brent Do you want to add the `@classmethod @property` solution as an answer? It should be included as an answer.

Comment: I haven't tested it myself so I'm not going to make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) to annotate class variables:

```
class RealSet:
    def __init__(self, intervals, *, canonicalize):
        pass

    EMPTY: ClassVar['RealSet']
    UNIVERSE: ClassVar['RealSet']


RealSet.EMPTY = RealSet(tuple(), canonicalize=False)
RealSet.UNIVERSE = RealSet(((None, None),), canonicalize=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Python 3.9 [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) can decorate other descriptors such as `property`. This way one can create a "classproperty":

```
class RealSet:
    def __init__(self, intervals, *, canonicalize):
        pass

    @classmethod
    @property
    def EMPTY(cls):
        return cls(tuple(), canonicalize=False)

    @classmethod
    @property
    def UNIVERSE(cls):
        return cls(((None, None),), canonicalize=False)
```