# Python access a class attribute without initializing?

Tags: python, oop

I have two files where each one contains a class:

```
# file1.py
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()

    @property
    def get(self):
        return self.d
    

obj1 = Class1()
obj1.d["a"] = 1
obj1.d["b"] = 2

# file2.py
from file1 import Class1 

class Class2:   
    def print_val(self):
        for i in Class1().get:
            print(i)
```

I am trying to access the attribute `d` from Class1 in Class2 without initializing Class1. The following currently returns an empty dict which makes sense.

```
Class2().print_val()
{}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using property() on classmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods)

Comment: You can't use instance variables without creating an instance.

Answer (score 3):

The class `Class1` does not have an attribute `d`.  Only objects of type `Class1` have an attribute `d`.  If you want to print the members of `obj1.d`, you can certainly do that, but you'll have to pass `obj1` to `print_val` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) on `Class1`, as you don't want to instantiate `Class1`.

```
class Class1:
    d = dict()


Class1.d['a'] = 'A'
Class1.d['b'] = 'B'


class Class2:
    def print_val(self):
        print(Class1.d)


c2 = Class2()
c2.print_val()
```

Out:

```
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
```