# Any way to initialize a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
class MyClass:
  my_var: Optional[str] = None

  @classmethod
  def get_my_var(cls) -> str:
    """ Sets cls.my_var if it's not set before """
    my_var = cls.my_var
    if my_var is not None:
       return my_var
    my_var = cls.some_func()
    cls.my_var = my_var
    return my_var
```

This reason I do this, instead of setting `my_var` in `self.__init__()` is because `MyClass` is often used without an instance, e.g.: `MyClass.my_var` and the callers expect `my_var` to have a default value from `cls.some_func()`

How can I achieve this in python 3.8+? Can I do a `@property` decorator here?  Can I force `MyClass` to assign `my_var` a value from `cls.some_func()`?

Comment: What have you tried, what happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using property() on classmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods)

Comment: Why are you deferring the initialization of the *class* attribute in the first place? A class attribute should be something that describes the *class*, independent of how many instances of the class exist.

Comment: A much simpler way to write `get_my_var` anyway would be `if cls.my_var is None: cls.my_var = cls.some_func()`, then `return cls.my_var`.

Comment: I mean, you can just do `MyClass.my_var = MyClass.some_func()` right after the class definition.

Comment: I don't understand, once class with a class variable of `my_var = None` has been initialized so has the class variable...  They are initialized with the class definition at runtime

Comment: @alexpdev yeah, I mean, it's a good point -- in Python, variables are simply defined, there is no seperate declaration/initialization step. `my_var = None` **is defining a variable, which is identical to "initializing it"**. But I think the OP means how to give it a value other than `None`